# Advanced list comprehension

Tags: python, list-manipulation

A list of ints is entered into the program 1 at a time, for example:

```
[1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1]
```

Task:

Print a list that contains exactly the same numbers as the given list,
but rearranged so that every 3 is immediately followed by a 4. The 3's must not move index places, but every other number may move.

The output of the example should read:

```
[1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4]
```

My code so far is only able to complete the rules 1 and 2. How could my code be modified to cater to this?

```
newList=[]

n=0

numCount= int(input())

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input())
    except:
        break
    if len(newList) !=(numCount):

        if  n == 3:
            newList.append(3)
            newList.append(4)
        else:
            newList.append(n)

print(newList)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand rule 1. Also, rules 2 and 4 are the same and incompatible with rule 5. Please re-formulate.

Comment: Yep rules are not compatible as it is, and what if the input by the user is not compatible? Do you want to add additional number to turn it compatible?

Comment: The example input and output is probably the best bet at seeing what has to be done.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I've edited the information format to make it easier to read. Hope that helps.

Comment: Every 3 has a number after it that is not a 3 or a 4, thus this is forbidden: `[3, 4]` and `[3, 3]`. A 3 appears in the list before any 4? Thus this `[3, 4]`? See the issue? ^^' (Included in your expected output!)

Comment: @Mathieu I think "every 3 has a number after it that is not a 3 or a 4" is for input list, not the output.

Comment: @Mathieu The main bit of logic required is prior to that statement so I'll remove it for clarity sake.

Comment: @RyanGrady Ask yourself: What should happen if a 4 is encountered in the input list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 If n is equal to 4 but n-1 is not equal to 3 than 4 must swap places with the nearest leading value to 3 that doesn't already have a 4. I've gotten close a few times.

Comment: @RyanGrady I have the impression you are making this 100x more complicated than it actually is.. I think this just boils down to *put a 4 after every 3 and make sure there is no other 4 that does not follow a 3*..

Comment: @RyanGrady Also **checking input** and **modifying for output** can be though off as two different and independent tasks to make your life (and thus ours too) easier.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I have the tendency to do that. However, if you can achieve what you said by not adding or removing any value from the list, but by rearranging it than that's it. I'd love to see it cause this questions got me pretty good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to first get all the indexes of 3 and 4 in the input list, then swap each element following a 3 with a 4. It gives the following code, which is quite short and easily readable:

```
a = [1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1]

# Get the indexes of 3 and 4 in the list
indexesOf3 = [i for i,elem in enumerate(a) if elem == 3]
indexesOf4 = [i for i,elem in enumerate(a) if elem == 4]

# Swap each element following a 3 with a 4
for i3,i4 in zip(indexesOf3,indexesOf4):
    a[i3+1], a[i4] = a[i4], a[i3+1]

print(a)
# [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4]
```

*Note: this code example modifies the input list, but obviously it can be easily updated into a function returning a new list and keeping the input list as it is.*

Comment: getting  the indexes of 3 and 4 can also be done by looping once over the list. I would suggest a `for` loop for that.

Comment: also a check like `a[-1]!=3` would be nice to make sure you don't get an error when doing `a[i3+1]`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks, I fully agree with you. In fact I did not look for optimization in this example, The goal was just to explain the used algorithm, so I keep it as it is.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis And I also agree, it could be enhanced. However if the last element of the input list is 3, then the task can not be achieved. I preferred to keep the code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function doing exactly that:

```
def arrange_list(my_list):
    # Copy the whole list
    arranged_list=myList.copy()

    # Find the all 4s
    index_of_4s=[i for i, x in enumerate(arranged_list) if x == 4]
    next_4=0

    # Loop over the whole list
    for i in range(len(arrangedList)):
        if(arrangedList[i]==3):  # We only care about 3s

            # We swap the previously found 4 with a 1
            arranged_list[index_of_4s[next_4]]=arranged_list[i+1]
            arranged_list[i+1]=4

            # We target the next 4
            next_4=next_4+1
    return arranged_list
```

If we test it with your example we get:

```
    myList=[1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1]
    arrange_list(myList)
    #> [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Basically, you just need to swap 4s and 1s. If you get the positions of all 4s and knowing that after every 3 there can only be a 1, you search for a 3 and swap the following 1 with a 4.

Comment: This works. however, how would you account for swapping the 4 with any given number(other than 3 of course)?

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You're question is not really well defined, and a lost of scenario are not taken into account. This code does the work quite simply, the idea is to create a new list.

-Find the position of the 3 in the input

-Place the 3, followed by a 4 in the new list

-Place the remaining elements.

```
input_list = [1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1]

# Check the number of 3 and 4
n3 = input_list.count(3)
n4 = input_list.count(4)

if n3 > n4:
    for i in range(n3-n4):
        input_list.append(4)
elif n4 > n3:
    for i in range(n4-n3):
        input_list.append(3)

# Now let's look at the order. The 3 should not move and must be followed by a 4.
# Easy way, create a new list.

output_list = [None for i in range(len(input_list))]

# Then I'm using numpy to go faster but the idea is just to extract the ids are which the 3 are placed.
import numpy as np

# Place the 3 and the 4
for elt_3 in np.where(np.asarray(input_list) == 3)[0]:
    output_list[elt_3] = 3
    output_list[elt_3+1] = 4 # Must be sure that the input_list does not end by a 3 !!!

# Then we don't care of the position for the other numbers.
other_numbers = [x for x in input_list if x != 3 and x != 4]

for i, elt in enumerate(output_list):
    if elt is None:
        output_list[i] = other_numbers[0]
        del other_numbers[0]

print (output_list)
```

In a more compact version with a single loop, it gives:

```
input_list = [1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1]
position_3 = np.where(np.asarray(input_list) == 3)[0]
other_numbers = [x for x in input_list if x != 3 and x != 4] # Not 3 and not 4
output_list = [None for i in range(len(input_list))]

for i, elt in enumerate(output_list):
    if elt == 4:
        continue
    elif i not in position_3:
        output_list[i] = other_numbers[0]
        del other_numbers[0]
    else:
        output_list[i] = 3
        output_list[i+1] = 4
```